# Is my Arduino Clone Broken - keeps outputting 1 without a sensor connected

Tags: arduino, clone

I tried to do a simple project where a 8x8 matrix lamp would display something different depending on whether or not a sensor outputted high/low.

There was no trouble getting the matrix lamp to work, as I wanted, but the sensor kept outputting 1, regardless if it was plugged in or not.

This is the code I used, but when I plugged in the sensor it would display 1/high continuously, and when I removed all wires from the sensor, the lamp would light occasionally and the monitor would display 1 as the movStat value.

The LED lamp is connected directly to the breadboard via. digital pin 4.

I am considering buying a new Arduino, but I would like to get a second hand opinion before I spend money on it.

I am using a PIR sensor model HC SR501:
[image]

```cpp
int movSens = 3;
int ledPin = 4;
int movStat = 0;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    //Sensor Setup
    pinMode(movSens, INPUT);
    //LED Setup
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    delay(1000);

    Serial.println(movSens);

    movStat = digitalRead(movSens);

    if (movStat == HIGH) { //If motion is detected, activate LED
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }

    Serial.println(movStat);
}
```

Comment: What flavor of Arduino are you using? 328? 2560?

Comment: @RamblinRose 2560 mega

Comment: the Arduino is OK. without a sensor it is a 'floating' pin. the sensor registers motion or is normal HIGH and sends a LOW pulse at motion

Comment: I may be mistaken and I don't have 2560 handy, but pin 4 = `PE2` which is XCK0/AIN0. Move the LED over to `PE3` (digital pin 5). Use the constants defined in `pins_arduino.h` and save yourself some aggravation.

Comment: Also I recommend posting Arduino questions over on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/